# 30° Celsius bottle conditioning. How bad is it?

Tags: bottling, temperature, bottle-conditioning

I have a problem my house is getting super hot during the summer, cannot find cool place to store my beer. I made a little insulated chamber but I seem not working at all. Recently I brewed an ale and fermentation temperature was in the normal range 18-20°C. Just worry if such high bottle conditioning temperature will affect the flavor?

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Not bad at all. The only time temperature control is crucial is during fermentation, not conditioning. I live in Queensland Australia where the temps exceed 30 Celsius regularly in the Summer and my beers turn out fine. It doesn't affect the taste or beer in any way I am aware of or have noticed.

Comment: Thanx,that's big relief for me.

Comment: Over time does the beer change its flavor? Like after six months is it still good?

Comment: Beer regardless of the temperature it is stored in, will change over time (variable factors make this non-linear and hard to predict). It depends what you added in and especially if you dry-hopped. I find after a few months, a dry-hopped IPA will lose a lot of its aroma for example. I wouldn't recommend keeping a beer bottled in 30 Celsius conditions for six months, although I would wonder where in the world are you if you're dealing with 30 Celsius all day and night, all year round.

Answer (score 3):

Temperature will affect the flavor in the long run, but you won't notice anything if it is only a short period of time.  Once bottle conditioning is complete, you better store your beer in a cool place, otherwise it will age prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but not horrible. You will probably have good beer, but it may go bad faster than under optional conditions. If you drink your beer within 2-3 months, you should be fine.